# Countdown timer does not receive a value input?

Tags: javascript

I have input with values. However, the countdown time cannot receive values. It just takes the default value. I have consulted on the Internet but it doesn't seem to work properly. Please give me a solution. Tks

HTML:

```
<div id="clockdiv">
<input type="text" value="1" id="day">
<input type="text" value="10" id="hours">
<input type="text" value="20" id="minutes">
<input type="text" value="5" id="seconds">
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    var dayget = document.getElementById("day").value;
    var hoursget = document.getElementById("hours").value;
    var minutesget = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
    var secondsget = document.getElementById("seconds").value;

    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + dayget * hoursget * minutesget * secondsget * 1000);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

Show time:

```
<span class="days"></span>
<span class="hours"></span>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<span class="seconds"></span>
```

Comment: All the `clock.querySelector` look for classes (`.days`, `.minutes`, etc). Maybe you intended to use an id? `#day`, `#minutes`. Or you don't have those classes in your HTML.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I am missing display classes. I have added the above updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to take your spans in your div. Because your querySelector search your span in this div

```js
let timeinterval;
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return {
            'total': t,
            'days': days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

            daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    
    function start(){
     clearInterval(timeinterval)
      var dayget = document.getElementById("day").value;
      var hoursget = document.getElementById("hours").value;
      var minutesget = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
      var secondsget = document.getElementById("seconds").value;

       var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + (dayget * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)+
          (hoursget * 1000 * 60 * 60 )+
          (minutesget * 1000 * 60)+
          (secondsget * 1000 )
          );
      initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
    
    }
    
    
    start();
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
<input type="text" value="1" id="day"oninput="start()">
<input type="text" value="10" id="hours"oninput="start()">
<input type="text" value="20" id="minutes"oninput="start()">
<input type="text" value="5" id="seconds"oninput="start()">
<br><br>

<span class="days"></span>
<span class="hours"></span>
<span class="minutes"></span>
<span class="seconds"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Tks Sir. I am learning about Javascript. Can you help me with this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556641/how-modal-bootstrap-always-shows-when-textbox-input-characters-set-timeout. Tks